# How do you correctly use Cupy's GPU accelerated library in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gpu, cupy

I am a complete beginner to parallel programming and would like to get into it. I've started using Cupy in a new python script I've been working on.
The task is to have many, many circles with 4 sections: x and y position, and an `x` and `y` velocity.
can anyone help me figure out how to use `cupy` in a way that would be faster?

Here's the python code with `cupy:

```py
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np

balls = cp.random.randint(0, 100, (100000, 4)).astype(cp.float32)
print(balls)
print(len(balls))

initballs = cp.RawKernel('''
      extern "C" __global__
      void init(float4* ball){
            int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
            ball[tid] = make_float4(ball[tid].x*800, ball[tid].y*600, 1.0, 0.);
      }
''', 'init')

updateballs = cp.RawKernel('''
      extern "C" __global__
      void update(float4* ball){
            int tid = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
            float x = ball[tid].x + ball[tid].z;
            float y = ball[tid].y + ball[tid].w;
            ball[tid] = make_float4(x, y, ball[tid].z, ball[tid].w);
            
      }
''', 'update')

initballs((len(balls),), (1,), (balls))

while True:
      starttime = time.time()
      updateballs((len(balls),), (1,), (balls))
      cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
      print(time.time()-starttime)
```

This confuses me because I can run the same thing in regular python and it seems to go faster?

```
import random, time

balls = []
for i in range(100000):
      balls.append([random.randrange(0, 800), random.randrange(0, 600), 1, 0])

def update():
      for ball in balls:
            ball[0] += ball[2]
            ball[2] += ball[3]

while True:
      starttime = time.time()
      update()
      print(time.time()-starttime)
```

Comment: You need to learn how GPUs work. GPUs are fast for SIMD friendly computations accessing contiguous blocks of data. The thing is the current kernel do not read data contiguously. Changing the input layout should fix this: `(4, 100000)` instead of `(100000, 4)`. In fact, this is also true for CPUs but having a scalar computation is less critical on CPUs. Besides, 100000 balls is not so much. GPUs are design for heavy computations. A kernel should last for a significant time. Otherwise, the overhead to start it can be bigger than the actual computation.

Comment: By the way, the kernel is mainly memory-bound. Thus, it will be faster only if your GPU has a higher memory bandwidth. While this is frequent, this is not always the case, especially on computing servers while multiple GPUs or some cheap PCs with low-end GPUs.

Comment: wow I didn't think this would work but it did. Many thanks!